# Build tables for ion auth and codeigniter

Tags: database, codeigniter, authentication

I have Codeigniter and Ion Auth installed on MAMP. I have the libraries working but I'm not sure how to build the required database tables for Ion Auth. Is there a preferred / best-practices way of doing this? Should I copy a query code from somewhere? Run a setup-db script? For that matter, with Codeigniter installed, is there any basic database setup that should be performed? All I have done is setup the ci_sessions table.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Oh - I figured this one out.

Just import the .sql file provided by Ion Auth - in my case I used PHPmyAdmin to import ion_auth.sql.

This built the `meta` table, *et al*

Comment: This is great, I wish this was included in the documentation http://benedmunds.com/ion_auth/